# Does an Azure Cosmos SQL database auto populate?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm running into an issue with some code I've been writing, my question is:

upon inputting a JSON object into an Azure Cosmos SQL database, are missing fields auto populated with None?

None seems to be popping up and breaking a few functions, curious if its an error in my code or its simply that my code is wrong!

```
2019-08-01T11:38:50+00:00,2019-08-01T11:39:30+00:00,40.0,
None,2019-08-01T17:12:40+00:00,,
```

rather curiously, upon outputting the database into a csv file there seems to be both None and empty fields?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and include more details. As it is currently written, it is not clear what's the problem you're facing.

Comment: What are you referring to by *"missing fields"*? Cosmos DB doesn't have a concept of "columns" like a relational database does; a document will only contain properties you specify. Please edit your question to provide more details about what you're doing, including code, so we can understand your issue better. I'm assuming there's some python code your question is based on, given the `python` tag.